# Line graph using ios charts swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-charts, linegraph

I am using **`ios chart`** to implement Line graph in Swift 3 . As in earlier versions of Swift, we had constructor to bind x values to Line graph, but there doesn't seems any such in Swift 3?

Kindly help if anyone has some inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please care to read the migration notes in [Release Notes](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/releases/tag/v3.0.0)

> - All dataset constructors have changed - they do not take an array of x-indices anymore.
> - All entry constructors have changed - they take in an X and a Y.

Basically, the x values are now taken from the entries.

If you want to change which values are displayed on the x-axis, you can change `xAxis.axisMinimum` and `xAxis.axisMaximum` and format them using `xAxis.valueFormatter`.

Answer (score 5):

Please try this to get your XAxis Values.

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class LineChartViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let populationData :[Int : Double] = [
            1990 : 123456.0,
            2000 : 233456.0,
            2010 : 343456.0
        ]

        let ySeries = populationData.map { x, y in
            return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y)
        }

        let data = LineChartData()
        let dataset = LineChartDataSet(values: ySeries, label: "Hello")
        dataset.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
        data.addDataSet(dataset)

        self.lineChartView.data = data

        self.lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = NSUIColor.white
        self.lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false;
        self.lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
        self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "LineChartView Example"
    }

    override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Thanks
Sriram

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979926/how-to-achieve-trackball-on-charts-in-swift-3x please help me too ?

Comment: @ShriRam, how to set dataset colour ? because the line ="dataset.colors = [NSUIColor.red]" is not affects

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

Example with barChart :

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class StatistiqueSafetyCheckViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ys1 = Array(1..<10).map { x in return sin(Double(x) / 2.0 / 3.141 * 1.5) }
        let ys2 = Array(1..<10).map { x in return cos(Double(x) / 2.0 / 3.141) }

        let yse1 = ys1.enumerated().map { x, y in return LineChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }
        let yse2 = ys2.enumerated().map { x, y in return LineChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }

        let data = LineChartData()
        let ds1 = LineChartDataSet(values: yse1, label: "Hello")
        ds1.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
        data.addDataSet(ds1)

        let ds2 = LineChartDataSet(values: yse2, label: "World")
        ds2.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
        data.addDataSet(ds2)

        self.lineChartView.data = data
        self.lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = NSUIColor.white
        self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "Linechart Demo"
    }

    override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change also circle ticket color:

```
 ds1.circleColors = [NSUIColor.blue]
 ds2.circleColors = [NSUIColor.red]
```