# Keep order of xAxis values using iOS Charts framework

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts, swiftcharts

I'm setting a CombinedChartView that have some value on xAxis, lets say (15, 16, 17, 2, 3)

with this line of code

```
for i in 0..<gameStatsMonth.count {

     let dataEntryTeam = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(gameStatsMonth[i].day!), y: Double(gameStatsMonth[i].points!))

     lineDataEntryTeam.append(dataEntryTeam)
}
```

It happens that the values are displayed sorted in xAxis, like this: 2, 3, 15, 16, 17.

There is any way to keep the first order of x values ? (the order on which they were inserted in lineDataEntryTeam)

Comment: Are you see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979926/how-to-achieve-trackball-and-access-label-above-bar-on-bar-charts-in-swift-3x/42019505#42019505

Comment: @mmarques I had meet the same issue, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an array for the xAxis (outside your functions):

```
var xaxisVals = [Double]()
```

Update your `for` loop

```
for i in 0..<gameStatsMonth.count {
    let dataEntryTeam = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(gameStatsMonth[i].day!), y: Double(gameStatsMonth[i].points!))
    xaxisVals.append(Double(gameStatsMonth[i].day!))
    lineDataEntryTeam.append(dataEntryTeam)
}
```

Adopt `IAxisValueFormatter`:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, IAxisValueFormatter
```

Fill the delegate method:

```
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    return xaxisVals[Int(value)]
}
```

In the class, define the delegate:

```
weak var axisFormatDelegate: IAxisValueFormatter?
```

In `viewDidLoad` set the delegate to `self`:

```
axisFormatDelegate = self
```

After the for loop, set the xAxis:

```
let xaxis = lineDataEntryTeam.xAxis
xaxis.granularityEnabled = true
xaxis.granularity = 1
xaxis.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
```

Comment: `return xaxisVals[Int(value)]` out of range in this case, `xaxisVals` contains all days, the `value` in the delegate method is not the index for `xaxisVals`, but for the value